# Rails: Search in has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, model

I have a model called **User** which `has_one` **Player**.  A **Player** `belongs_to` a **User**.

I want to find all the Players which Users attributes City has a particular value.  Right now I have this in my Player model:

```
def find
  User.find(:all, :conditions => ['city LIKE ?', "%#{city}%"])
end
```

However that gives me the User.  I want the Players which Users satisfy that condition.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
Player.joins(:user).where('user.city LIKE ?', "%#{city}%")
```

Comment: I get this error: Unknown column 'user.city' in 'where clause' -- I have tried doing a join and it works:  self.joins(:user).find(:all, :conditions => ['users.city LIKE ?', "%#{city}%"]) - But I don't know if the join is necessary...

Comment: @HommerSmith Yep, a join is necessary because you need to check the relation data.